# Html/JS show password in input after Blur/Focus

Tags: javascript, html, input

I have simple form wich contains password field:

```
<input required type="password" value="Insert password" style="color:#888;" onfocus="inputFocus(this)"  onblur="inputBlur(this)">
```

JS functions are (after click clear and change color..):

```
function inputFocus(input) {
    if (input.value === input.defaultValue) {
        input.value = "";
        input.style.color = "#000";
    }
}
function inputBlur(input) {
    if (input.value === "") {
        input.value = input.defaultValue;
        input.style.color = "#888";
    }
}
```

If i load page, i want see standard value in input field. For type `type="text"` it is not problem, but for `type="password"` i see only dots. 
I want to see the default value(Insert password) , but when the user begins typing a password he must see dots.

How?

Thank you for your reply.

Comment: Do you realize browsers have this built in? The placeholder attribute.

Comment: if you want to show the user their typed in password you can use attr("type", "text"); or attr("type", "password"); but for the placeholder you should use above suggestion

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the placeholder attribute:

```html
   <input required type="password" placeholder="Insert password" />
```

Answer (score 0):

How about an HTML5 placeholder? You don't need JavaScript for this:

```
<input required type="password" placeholder="Insert password" style="color:#888;">
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer is quite simple - instead of using the `value` property for "insert password", use `placeholder`.

```
<input type="password" placeholder="insert password">
```

http://jsfiddle.net/763bjejn/